# joint_state_publisher window is not shown

Tags: joint-state-publisher, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

this is my launch file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <!-- upload urdf -->
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find robot_arm_pkg)/urdf/arduino_robot_arm.urdf" />

  <!-- Combine joint values -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/>

  <!-- Show in Rviz   -->
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find robot_arm_pkg)/launch/config.rviz" />

  <!-- send joint values -->
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="use_gui" value="True"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

I'm using the joint_state_publisher GUI to control a robot in Rviz, the problem is the joint_state_publisher window is not appear. I already installed the joint_state_publisher and joint_state_publisher_gui by using:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joint-state-publisher
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-joint-state-publisher-gui
```

there are no errors are shown when I launch the file

By the way, I tested the same package and launch file in another system and it works fine

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363410/joint_state_publisher-window-is-not-shown/) by [Moneera Banjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/60255/moneera-banjar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2020-10-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the update split of the GUI capabilities of the `joint_state_publisher` into its own package, it is now recommended  to run that node separately. In future releases the `use_gui` parameter will no longer be used. If you had an `output="screen"` attribute in your `joint_state_publisher` `<node>` tag. You'd see a warning like the following:

> The 'use_gui' parameter was specified,
> which is deprecated.  We'll attempt to
> find and run the GUI, but if this
> fails you should install the
> 'joint_state_publisher_gui' package
> instead and run that.  This backwards
> compatibility option will be removed
> in Noetic.

Now as to why this same launch file worked on another system... a bit of a mystery, but my best guess is that the other system didn't have the same package versions. Nominally, in Kinetic (which you seem to be using), the GUI should still pop up. That said, I'm curious what would happen if you took the advice of the above warning and did things the currently-recommended way -- does your issue disappear? My launch files now usually have a snippet similar to the following:

```
<arg name="use_gui" default="true" doc="Should the joint_state_publisher use a GUI for controlling joint states" />
<node pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" name="joint_state_publisher" output="screen" unless="$(arg use_gui)" />
<node pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui" type="joint_state_publisher_gui" name="joint_state_publisher_gui" output="screen" if="$(arg use_gui)" />
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moneera Banjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/60255/moneera-banjar/) on 2020-10-16**:
Thank you for your help, it works correctly
I realize that the current machine uses joint_state_publisher package installed from source, and the other machine uses the package installed from binaries .. this might cause the issue and the two packages have different versions!

**Comment by [AllOutMayhem](https://answers.ros.org/users/136107/alloutmayhem/) on 2023-01-31**:
Hi, when you say "the other machine", which other machine are you referring to?